# Zend Framework view render takes a lot of memory

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

I try to create emails for next sending with my cron php script.
And I use Zend_View for rendering email template.
I have 50k users but 3000 emails was created with 64MB memory limit and 7200 with 128MB.
Code of rendering emails

```
public function prepareEmailBody($template, $templates)
{
    $view = new Zend_View(array('basePath' => './application/views'));
    $template_file_name = $template . '.phtml';
    foreach ($templates as $key => $value) {
       $view->$key = $value;
    }
    $body = $view->render('mails/' . $template_file_name);
    return $body
}
```

And use this method in

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
.....
$text = Mailer::getInstance()->prepareEmailBody($template, $vars);
.....
}
```

Please advice how optimize code.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code. What you just pasted only uses a single Zend_View. And anyway, welcome to the world of Zend_Framework. It's memory intensive.. that's why you should use APC and Cache everything.

Comment: I can't cache rendered views because data of each user paste in this template.

Comment: and really problem is using view rendering because if I write $text = 'some text'; then all 50k emails were created.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using one View object and the partial helper instead, this might improve things (or might make it slower).

```
public function getView()
{
    if (!$this->_view) {
        $this->_view = new Zend_View(array('basePath' => './application/views'));
    }

    return $this->_view;
}

public function prepareEmailBody($template, $templates)
{
    $template_file_name = $template . '.phtml';

    $body = $this->getView()->partial($template_file_name, $templates);
    return $body
}
```

Comment: This code makes it slower. Partial helper use render method but before make copy of view with line $view = $this->cloneView(); and I think this line makes it slower. I can't understand where is memory leak in method render: `public function render($name)
    {
        // find the script file name using the parent private method
        $this->_file = $this->_script($name);
        unset($name); // remove $name from local scope

        ob_start();
        $this->_run($this->_file);

        return $this->_filter(ob_get_clean()); // filter output
    }` I thought ob_get_clean() clears memory.

Comment: Worth a try! Perhaps instead you could try using one View object but with render, and unsetting the variables from the view before returning $body?

Comment: If use one View object then variables (it has same name) will replaced with new value in memory and it'll not use more memory or not?

Comment: Now It works with getView() and without unsets. I think problem was that View object argument was passed by value and php tried create many copies of passed argument in memory.